# CSS position of content

Tags: html, css, css-position

The Image below is a representation of my webpage:

[image]

Now the issue is when I reduce the screen size to anything less than 620px, The layout should be like :

[image]

whereas it is coming something like this:

[image]

From the Pictures, you can clearly find out two issues:

My CSS for menu:

```
#menu
    {
    width: 160px;
    height: 257px;
    background-color:#878787;   
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:50px;
    float:left;
    }
```

Below is the CSS for content:

```
#content
{
width: 620px;
float: right;
margin-right: 50px;
}
```

and here is a CSS for the text in content:

```
#top
{
margin-top:-3px;
padding-top:55px;
padding-bottom:77px;
padding-left:35px;
padding-right:30px; 
background-color: white;
}
```

Can anyone provide me the solution for the same. 
I want 50px space on the left of the content which shall disappear with the reduce in resolution. In addition, I need my content text to wrap menu.

Comment: link please of jsfiddle

Comment: On the CSS of the menu, you have position:absolute; and float:left;. These statements don't work together because absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal flow.

Comment: use media query for responsive desin

Answer (score 1):

TRy

```
#top
{
margin-top:-3px;
padding-top:55px;
padding-bottom:77px;
padding-left:35px;
padding-right:30px; 
background-color: white;
position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding another element with float left on it.  This could be an invisible element. Its a tricky one, making text wrap around stuff isn't hard, but your layout *also* has the text totally separate from it at first. `Float` is an ideal way to make text wrap around stuff.

In light of this you may need to come up with a (slightly) radical layout swap at different screen sizes using media queries. I've made a pen here showing one example of what could happen. This is just intended to guide you in the right direction, it won't completely solve your problem.

### Example

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/cfBet/

#### *Please resize the browser to make it work*

In the example:

### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="float"></div>
  <div class="text">Lorem .... repellat!</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.text{
  width:600px;
  padding-left:30px;
}

.float{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#f00;
  float:left;
}

.wrap{
  max-width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width:800px){
  .text{
    width:600px;
    padding-left:300px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you do something clever with before and after elements?

Comment: i can edit only CSS file to this html: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gst54gpkqpva901/XDsceScjCo